# image zoom in meteor android cordova

Tags: image, cordova, meteor, zooming

I am building a chat application using Meteor for Android. I have included "Add Image" option using cordova camera plugin. Now, after the image is uploaded and is seen by the users, I want to click on it and zoom it. How to proceed?

Here's my image rendering code :

```html
<div class="message">
     <img src="{{t.img}}" 
         data-action="zoom" 
         class="showImage" 
     >
</div>
```

I've tried using the `inno:zoom` package but was unsuccessful. Any insights?

In the html head, i have the following code :

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’d suggest using a touch library such as Hammerjs: http://hammerjs.github.io/

There are a lot of ways to work with touch in JavaScript, but they can be difficult if you aren’t experienced with them.

You may have to put the uploaded image in its own template and use reactive variables to re-initialize the image element in order to enact the zoom feature. This is likely also true of the package you already tried.

If you could share more code samples, I (or others) might be able to give a more specific answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I shall now try uploading the image in its own template.Updating the question and displaying more code

Comment: Okay so I am now using a new template to just display the image. have applied the inno package too but still its not zoomable

Comment: This might be a wild hair, but what if you decrease the width of the `<img>` element's from 100% to 50%? Looking in inno:zoom's source code, it looks like the `zoom` function is returning if the element is wider than (100vw-80px*2). https://github.com/spinningarrow/zoom-vanilla.js/blob/gh-pages/js/zoom-vanilla.js

Comment: Well, dang. Maybe you should add a bit more information to your question. For example, what helpers are serving data to the template? What events are involved? What CSS are you currently using? Do you have any console/javascript errors when you attempt to zoom? Do you have to use inno:zoom or would you be open to another library? People can really only guess based on what you've provided.

Comment: edited my code. i dont have any error on the console. I am open to use any free library

Comment: Solved, using hammer.js